# String Type Vector C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, vector, output

In the code I shared below, I want to output vector data type in the `AddStoreCustomer()` section. This is how the code works. But there is a bug in the code. If I enter a single word in the customer variable, the code works fine. But when I enter two words in  this variable with a space between them,the code doesn't work.

```
    #include <iostream>
        #include <vector>
    
        using namespace std;
    
        class Store {
            int StoreID;
            string StoreName;
            string StoreCity;
            string StoreTown;
            string StoreTel;
            vector <string> StoreCustomer;
    
            public:
               Store(){}
               Store(int sid, string sname, string scity, string stown, string stel, string scustomer) {
                  setStoreID(sid);
                  setStoreName(sname);
                  setStoreCity(scity);
                  setStoreTown(stown);
                  setStoreTel(stel);
                  setStoreCustomer(scustomer);
               }
               void setStoreID(int sid) {
                  StoreID = sid;
               }
               void setStoreName(string sname) {
                  StoreName = sname;
               }
               void setStoreCity(string scity) {
                  StoreCity = scity;
               }
               void setStoreTown(string stown) {
                 StoreTown = stown;
               }
               void setStoreTel(string stel) {
                 StoreTel = stel;
               }
               void setStoreCustomer(string scustomer) {
                 StoreCustomer.push_back(scustomer);
               }
               int getStoreID() {
                  return StoreID;
               }
               string getStoreName() {
                 return StoreName;
               }
        
    
        string getStoreCity() {
                return StoreCity;
            }
        string getStoreTown() {
            return StoreTown;
        }
        string getStoreTel() {
            return StoreTel;
        }
        vector <string> getStoreCustomer() {
            return StoreCustomer;
        }
    
        ~Store(){}
    };
    
        Store s2[50];

    void AddStore() {
    int id, menu;
    string name, city, town, tel;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        cout << "Lutfen Magaza ID Numarasini Girin: ";
        cin >> id;
        s2[i].setStoreID(id);
        cout << "Lutfen Magaza Adini Girin: ";
        cin >> name;
        s2[i].setStoreName(name);
        cout << "Lutfen Magazanin Bulundugu Ili Girin: ";
        cin >> city;
        s2[i].setStoreCity(city);
        cout << "Lutfen Magazanin Bulundugu Ilceyi Girin: ";
        cin >> town;
        s2[i].setStoreTown(town);
        cout << "Lutfen Magazanin Telefon Numarasini Girin: ";
        cin >> tel;
        s2[i].setStoreTel(tel);
        cout << "Magaza Eklendi" << endl;
        cout << "\n\n";
    }
    cout << "Menuye Donmek icin 0 " << endl;
    cin >> menu;
    if (menu == 0) {
        StoreMenu();
    }
    else {
        cout << "Tanımlanamayan Giris!!!" << endl;
        //Menu();
    }
}


int Search2(const int& y) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        if (s2[j].getStoreID() == y)
            return j;
    }
    return -1;
}
    
    void AddStoreCustomer() {
        int id, found, menu;
        string customer;
        cout << "Lutfen Musteri Eklemek Istediginiz Magazanin ID Numarasini Girin:";
        cin >> id;
        found = Search2(id);
        if (found == -1)
        {
            cout << "Magaza Bulunamadi" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Magaza Bulundu.\n" << "Lutfen Magaza Veri Tabanina Eklemek Istediginiz Musterinin Bilgilerini Girin: ";
            cin >> customer;
            s2[found].setStoreCustomer(customer);
            cout << "Girilen Musteri Bilgisi Secilen Magazaya Eklendi";
            cout << "Magaza ID: " << s2[found].getStoreID() << "\n Magaza Adi: " << s2[found].getStoreName() << "\n Magazanin Bulundugu Il: " << s2[found].getStoreCity() << "\n Magazanin Bulundugu Ilce:" << s2[found].getStoreTown() << "\n Magaza Iletisim Numarasi: " << s2[found].getStoreTel() << endl;
            cout << "Musteriler: " << endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < s2[found].getStoreCustomer().size(); i++)
            {
                cout << "\t\t" << s2[found].getStoreCustomer()[i] << endl;
            }
        }
        cout << "Tekrar Giris Yapmak icin 1                    Menuye Donmek icin 0 " << endl;
        cin >> menu;
        if (menu == 0) {
            StoreMenu();
        }
        else if (menu == 1) {
            AddStoreCustomer();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are using `cin>>` to read input, which reads until the first whitespace symbol. If you want to read a whole line, consider using [`std::getline()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) instead:

```
getline(cin, customer);
```

Comment: More accurately, "*This happens because you are using **operator>>** to read input*". `std::cin` itself doesn't care what the input is. It is things like `operator>>` and `std::getline()` that provide meaning and semantics to the data that `std::cin` (or any `std::istream`) provides to them.

Comment: Small note : Not only \s but also newline (\n)

Comment: thx for good edits <3 (somehow thought \n is in \s symbols)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I revised the code. However, when I run the code, it outputs directly without asking me for input. I wonder if I used `getline()` the wrong way I updated it to `getline(cin,customer)` instead of `cin>> customer`